Do we ever figure out whose brain is in the jar?
In Jack Move, in the original lab (and the Construct lab), we see a brain in a jar. Noa makes a big deal over this, leading me to think the brain belongs to someone significant.
Do we ever discover whose brain it is?


If someone can edit this with a picture of the original cutscene in the lab where Noa refers to the brain and freaks out, I would really appreciate it!
